# How to override a method in another page in WP8?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, nfc, overriding

I am working on an app involving reading an NFC tag via the ProximityDevice class. The idea is when the tag is successfully read on the main_page, it will navigate to the second_page where all the processing of the tag content will be done. When it reaches the second_page, the app must not be able to read any tag anymore, unless it goes back to the main_page.

The problem is when the app navigates to the second_page, it still reads tags and executes the methods I declared on the main_page. It seems like the methods are inherited on the second_page.

Is there a way to:
(1) fully disable reading proximity devices, and re-enable it when necessary; OR
(2) override the inherited methods from the main_page?

I have tried:
(1) using stopSubscribingForMessage right before navigating to the next page, BUT it still reads the succeeding tags;
(2) declaring new methods for reading tags on the second_page - these new methods were executed, ALONG with the methods from the main_page.

Here's my code:

(main_page)

```
public MainPage()
{
InitializeComponent();
device = ProximityDevice.GetDefault();
        if (device != null)
        {
            device.DeviceArrived += ProximityDeviceArrived;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to initialize proximity device.");
        }

}

public void ProximityDeviceArrived(Windows.Networking.Proximity.ProximityDevice device)
{
device.SubscribeForMessage("NDEF", ProcessDeviceMessage);
}

public void ProcessDeviceMessage(ProximityDevice sender, ProximityMessage message)
{
//reads tag content
sender.StopSubscribingForMessage(message.SubscriptionId);
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Result.xaml?tagContent=" + tagContent, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

(second_page)

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        string tagContent = NavigationContext.QueryString["tagContent"];
        //process tag content
    device = ProximityDevice.GetDefault();
        if (device != null)
        {
            device.DeviceArrived += ProximityDeviceArrived;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to initialize proximity device.");
        }
}

public void ProximityDeviceArrived(Windows.Networking.Proximity.ProximityDevice device)
{
        device.SubscribeForMessage("NDEF", ProcessDeviceMessage);
}

public void ProcessDeviceMessage(ProximityDevice sender, ProximityMessage message)
{
        Debug.WriteLine("You tapped your tag again. I will do nothing.");
}
```

I really hope you could help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods are not inherited by the second page, it's just that you didn't unsubscribe properly from the message.

Did you try using the return value of `SubscribeFromMessage()` instead of `message.SubscriptionId` to call `StopSubscribingForMessage()`?

This is what the API doc suggests.

Comment: Thank you! How can I overlook that.